# Unable to run ember commands when I use ember version 2.9.1

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

I initially installed and started trying hands on using latest ember. Everthing worked fine. But my company uses ember-cli@2.9.1, so I uninstalled and installed version 2.9.1

Now when I try the command ember --version / ember -v I am getting the below error

```
[~]$ ember --version                                                                               
WARNING: Node v10.24.1 has currently not been tested against Ember CLI and may result in unexpected behaviour.
Invalid Version: 2023.01.30.00
TypeError: Invalid Version: 2023.01.30.00
    at new SemVer (/Users/*****/.nvm/versions/node/v10.24.1/lib/node_modules/ember-cli/node_modules/semver/semver.js:323:11)
    at Range.test (/Users/*****/.nvm/versions/node/v10.24.1/lib/node_modules/ember-cli/node_modules/semver/semver.js:1203:15)
    at Function.satisfies (/Users/*****/.nvm/versions/node/v10.24.1/lib/node_modules/ember-cli/node_modules/semver/semver.js:1257:16)
    at /Users/*****/.nvm/versions/node/v10.24.1/lib/node_modules/ember-cli/lib/models/watcher.js:116:18
    at tryCatch (/Users/*****/.nvm/versions/node/v10.24.1/lib/node_modules/ember-cli/node_modules/rsvp/dist/rsvp.js:525:12)
    at invokeCallback (/Users/*****/.nvm/versions/node/v10.24.1/lib/node_modules/ember-cli/node_modules/rsvp/dist/rsvp.js:538:13)
    at publish (/Users/*****/.nvm/versions/node/v10.24.1/lib/node_modules/ember-cli/node_modules/rsvp/dist/rsvp.js:508:7)
    at flush (/Users/*****/.nvm/versions/node/v10.24.1/lib/node_modules/ember-cli/node_modules/rsvp/dist/rsvp.js:2415:5)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:61:11)
```

I am using Node v10.24.1. Any help in getting this fixed pls ?

Answer (score 0):

That version is ancient! I recommend using a node version manager like Volta or nvm for your Ember work and install nodejs version 0.12. And please encourage your company to upgrade, for security reasons if nothing else.